# How to change the Facebook comments text color?

Tags: html

[image]

I'm using Facebook comments plugin for the FAQ page. However, the default comments text color is not suitable for the dark background theme. It is great if you guys could give me some valuable suggestions and comments how to adjust.

**Configuration Code**

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `data-colorscheme="light"` with `data-colorscheme="dark"` to solve your problem.

No color customization is documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Answer (score -1):

You can just using  style attribute to `<div>` tag and give what color you want.I gave red. **`style="color:red;"`**

```html
<div style="color:red;" class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light">This is some text!</div>
```

Comment: But comments are rendered in iframe, aren't them?